# multi-range slider with html5 input range in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you are using Angular 4, you are probably suffering if you need to use a range slider. Most of the packages available are for AngularJS or Angular 2 that doesn't work flawless.

So, I'm trying to build up a cross browser multiple range slider with native html5 input ranges. However, when it comes to IE and Edge, it seems there is a little issue understanding the pointer events for pseudo elements and it doesn't work.

Although I'm using Angular 4, I just created a JSFiddle in AngularJS as an example as I believe this is more a CSS issue maybe with a Javascript workaround.

I appreciate your help. Thanks,

```
#filter .slider_container{
    display: block;
    width: 99.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 15%;
    min-height: 85px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
    box-shadow:         0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0);
    margin-top:1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#filter .slider_container p{
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 5%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #000000;
}

#filter .slider_container p:nth-of-type(1){
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   margin-bottom: 0;
   padding-top:10px;
}

#filter .slider_container .gender{
    outline: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
    width: 45%;
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 150px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0.8%;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0.65em;
}

#filter .slider_container .gender:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
#filter .slider_container .gender:hover{
        background-color: #EA0A8A;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EA0A8A, #ec5aae);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#EA0A8A, #ec5aae);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#EA0A8A, #ec5aae);
        background-image: linear-gradient(#EA0A8A, #ec5aae);
        /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black , 0 0 25px black , 0 0 5px black;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);*/
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.30);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.30);
        box-shadow:         0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.30);
        border: 0px solid #ffffff;

}

#filter .slider_container .active{
    background: #EA0A8A;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
}


#filter input[type=range]{
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
    width: 80%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
    background: transparent; /* Otherwise white in Chrome */
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#filter input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#filter input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
}

#filter input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

    /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
    background: transparent; 
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}

/* Special styling for WebKit/Blink */
#filter input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 3vh;
    width: 3vh;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -14px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; /* Add cool effects to your sliders! */
     max-height: 15px;
    max-width: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
#filter input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 3vh;
    width: 3vh;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
     max-height: 15px;
    max-width: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
#filter input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-height: 15px;
    max-width: 15px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: -3px;
}



#filter input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none transparent;
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    }

#filter input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: none transparent;
    }

#filter input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: none transparent;
    border-radius: 1.3px;
    border: 20px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    }

#filter input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 16px 0;
    color: transparent;
    z-index: -9;
    border: 20px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    }

#filter input[name='distanceslider']::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #EA0A8A;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    border-radius: 2.6px;

    }
#filter input[name='distanceslider']:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #EA0A8A;
    }
#filter input[name='distanceslider']::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #c5c5c5;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    border-radius: 2.6px;
    }
#filter input[name='distanceslider']:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #c5c5c5;
    }

#filter .ghost{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

 #filter .ghost::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

 #filter .ghost::-moz-range-thumb {
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events: all;
 }

 #filter .ghost::-ms-thumb {
    z-index:1;
    pointer-events: all;
 }

 #filter .ghost::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    z-index: -10;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#filter .ghost:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
   z-index: -10;
   pointer-events: none;
}

#filter .ghost::-moz-range-track {
    z-index: -10;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#filter .ghost::-ms-track {
    z-index: -40;
    pointer-events: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#filter .ghost::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: none transparent;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    border-radius: 2.6px; 
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -9;
}
#filter .ghost:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: none transparent;;
}
#filter .ghost::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #c5c5c5;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    border-radius: 2.6px;
}
#filter .ghost:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #c5c5c5;
}


#filter .main{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

 #filter .main::-webkit-slider-thumb{
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#filter .main::-moz-range-thumb {
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: all;
 }
#filter .main::-ms-thumb{
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
#filter .main::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
   z-index: -11;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#filter .main:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  z-index: -11;
   pointer-events: none;
}

#filter .main::-moz-range-track {
   z-index: -11;
   border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 15px;
}
#filter .main::-ms-track {
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#filter .main::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #c5c5c5;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    border-radius: 2.6px; 
}
#filter .main:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: #c5c5c5;
}
#filter .main::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #EA0A8A;
    border: 0px solid #010101;
    border-radius: 2.6px;
}
#filter .main:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: #EA0A8A;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/guarinex/00Lh7kfd/28/

Comment: Hi check https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ion-range-slider